# What is the logic behind X and Y axis in PDF?

Tags: pdf, tcpdf, fpdi

I'm updating a PDF dynamically using [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) and [FPDI](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/). Everything works properly there.

However, I cannot understand the way [`SetXY()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a00ec13928f57b17c21040acc881fe482) works.

What are exactly the X and Y axis values? Milimeters? Letter spacing from the edge?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're measured in millimeters [by default](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#aad2c0cbfe5b6330eed5850f87c2a32d9). However you can change it using the function setPageUnit.

The X (abscissa) and Y (ordinate) values are by default started from the top-left hand side of the document/page. However this can be changed using RTL (right-to-left) mode using the [setRTL](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a7d067c080614c7f55b6623adfc80a1c1) function.